# How to pass an input parameter for a UDF to sapply

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, sapply

I have a vector of values and a user defined function with multiple parameters. I want to sapply my UDF to every value in this vector while every entry in this vector is also an input parameter for the UDF

```
t <- 1:5
myfunc <- function (setvar, var){
    return(setvar * var)
}

sapply(t, myfunc(setvar = 2), var = t)
```

So in this case the result I'd like would be:

```
2 4 6 8 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
sapply(t, myfunc, setvar = 2)
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Or to understand what exactly you are passing use an anonymous function

```
sapply(t, function(x) myfunc(2, x))
```

Also `t` is a base function in R, so it is better to use some other name for your variables.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This perfectly works. Comming from a perl background where everything is done by loops R is still confusing to me sometimes.